# UWP 10 XAML Strikeout Content in Checkbox

Tags: c#, xaml, checkbox, uwp, strikethrough

I am Building a To-Do-List App and want to strikeout the Content in my Checkbox if it is Checked.
But i dont know how.
Can maybe someone help me?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox x:Name="checkBoxToDo" 
                                      IsChecked="{Binding istErledigt, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      Content="{Binding ToDoName}"  />
                        </StackPanel>
```

```
internal class ToDoViewModel
   {
       public string ToDoName { get; set; }
       public bool istErledigt { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: could you tell more detail about strikeout the content in the checkbox?

Comment: Hi Nico, in my App i have a textbox where i write my "to do" in. After that i click on my save button and save it. The saved "ToDoName" are displayed in the content of checkbox. 
I try to find out how my Content "ToDoName" gets strikethrough if i am check the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP 10 XAML Strikeout Content in Checkbox

For the requirement, you could make value converter to edit textblock's TextDecorations property base on `IstErledigt` viewmodel property, for more please refer the following code.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:ToDoViewModel x:Name="ViewModel" />
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <local:BoolConverter x:Key="BoolConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

<CheckBox
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    IsChecked="{Binding IstErledigt, Mode=TwoWay}"
    >
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding ToDoName}" TextDecorations="{Binding IstErledigt, Converter={StaticResource BoolConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </TextBlock>
</CheckBox>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public class ToDoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ToDoName { get; set; }
    private bool _isErledigt;

    public bool IstErledigt
    {
        get
        {
            return _isErledigt;
        }
        set
        {
            _isErledigt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public class BoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return (bool)value == true ? TextDecorations.Strikethrough : TextDecorations.None;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Nico!! I build my application like in the answer from you, but i only have a error. In my xaml Page i get the error "Cannot find "DateContext" in the Typ "Page"". I tried to figure out how to solve this problem but i am not succesfull.

Comment: Please check this [line](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App69/blob/master/App69/MainPage.xaml#L13).

Comment: I checked your coder, you just implement `ToDoViewModel` but you have not give the property value. please check this [line](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/App69/blob/master/App69/MainPage.xaml.cs#L37).

Comment: I Change it in: 
ToDoViewModel.ToDoName = "Doooo";
ToDoViewModel._istErledigt = false;
- now it says, i Need a Objectreference…. do you know what this mean?

Comment: `ViewModel.IstErledigt = false;` but not _istErledigt .

Comment: If  you have declared page datacontext in the xaml, please avoid set it again in the code behind.

Comment: Ahh yes i try and all the errors are fixed. But i can't create a new todo and see it in a new Checkbox.
I wanted to have a App where i write my todo in my TextBox and when i click on the Button "Speichern" it should display in a Checkbox.
I think i delete something in my code but cant find what i delete. If you have time, can you maybe look again?

Comment: You need to place the checkbox in the listview and bind to do list.

Comment: Your answer is really helpful thank you for all your help. I am still trying to display my todos.

Comment: Please insert `checkbox` in to  listview data-template. and implement collection in the `MainPageViewModel`.

Comment: sorry but what do you mean with "insert checkbox in to listview data-template". Do you mean that i should insert my checkbox tag in the listview tag?

Comment: `ListView` contains `ItemTemplate` property you could insert checkbox like the following   `ListView has <ListView> <ListView.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate> <CheckBox/></DataTemplate> </ListView.ItemTemplate></ListView>` for more please refer  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/listview-and-gridview)

Comment: Nico i have a question again.. i hope not to disturb you but i think you are the best in uwp apps...
When i am click on the checkbox my text gets strikethrough and i like to create a button that when you click on it, it deletes all the checkboxes that are "true" (or strikethrough).
I try it with: 
if(listeToDo.IstErledigt == true){ 
listeToDo.RemoveAt(viewToDos.SelectedIndex); }
else {}
Do you maybe have an better idea? Thank you for all your help

Comment: Sure, you could make a button and foreach the todo collection in the click event, if the item's `IstErledigt` equal to true then remove it from the collection.

Comment: My to do list app is completly working now. Thank you so much!